# How to use django-notification to send an anonymous notification to a user

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-notification

I've implemented a notification sending when the certain object is changed.

```
  notify.send(request.user, #UserA
              recipient=worker.profile.user, #UserB
              target=application, 
              verb="Your object has been changed")
```

Here is the example of such notification "***UserA*: Your object *Obj* has been changed**".

But for my case I need to send this notification anonymously (just not display the name of *UserA* in notification) e.g. just "**Your object *Obj* has been changed**", but I still need the info about sender.

I couldn't find any examples of such use of django-notification system, but it is mentioned in the documentation that there is an anonymous usage of the fields.

- I've tried to set sender field to None. But it has to be not empty.
- I've also tried to set actor field. Name of *request.user* is still mentioned in notification.

Comment: I understand that probably the problem lies in displaying the notification, but if there is the way to not change it, it would be great

Comment: Not really an answer, but maybe you can create user with username system and pass them as first arg to .send method? Then notification would be "System: sth sth sth"